# FOR statement to query a SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a query against a database with a for statement (in C#)
something like this:

```
List<object> data = new List<object>();

for(int i = 0; i < executeScalar("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable"); i++)
{
      List[i] = executeRead("SELECT rownumber(i) From mytable");
      // or
      executeUpdate("UPDATE mytable SET ... inrownumber(i)",List[i])
}
```

and the question is: is there any function to use for this "rownumber(i)" and "inrownumber(i)"?

I know I can do it like this

```
List[i] = executeRead("SELECT * From mytable WHERE ROW_NUMBER() = " + i);
```

and

```
executeUpdate("UPDATE mytable SET ... WHERE ROW_NUMBER() = " + i,List[i])
```

but if I do that - the database will search in all the table each time to find one item, so if I have 100 items, the database will pass on 10,000 items. and I wont that each time the database go directly to the row, so it pass only 100 items in all the for statement

Do you know any way do do it?

(I need it because in my program - the developer assumed that all the data is in the list, and he take them with a for statement and by index, and do "Add" and "Insert" and so on, and I don't wont to change all the program)

Thanks

Comment: Where did you think you could use WHERE ROW_NUMBER() = ? The Function is a windows function and requires more information to work on, e.g. Row_Number() Over (Order By <Column>). Also please provide more specific information, especially some example table data and an example of what you'd prefer to see. As it is your question is too confusing to answer.

Comment: Why do you have to update each row and you query it?  Would it not be more efficient to select everything from the table, and update everything all at once?

Comment: I meant "OVER ORDER BY  id" - where id is the primary key. I think it's automatic when you take all the row. no?   to select all the data is too large for the memory.

Comment: It's incredibly inefficient to run a new query to the database inside a for loop. _Much_ better is to use a JOIN so that you can pull back all of data in one trip to the database. Also: string concatenation is a very bad way to substitute values into your queries. It leaves you vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: Rachel - I didn't understand what information you need. Joel - so your's answer is that I can't use the "for"? I know it is not a normal way. but I hoped maybe it's can be done

Comment: Not sure what's so confusing about asking for sample data and an explanation of what the data would be before AND after an operation. The fact you're asking such basic questions regarding using set based as opposed to row based logic is also worrying. Joel never said you can't use a for loop, just that it's about the worst method possible. Please remember we're trying to help YOU. But please help US by providing more information and listening to what we say as opposed to fighting us. There are, after all, plenty of other questions out there with magic beanz attached.

Comment: maybe I didn't explain well my methods. in tne "executeRead" method I read one row in the database and convert it to an object. in the "executeUpdate" method - i take an object, assign his parameters in a command and execute it/ it's more clear now?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to treat a table like it's an array.  What you're missing is that a table isn't an array.  By definition and design, a table is an *unordered* collection of records.  What you're doing here can be made to execute, but it's not the right way to work with a table.  If you want a unique identifier for a row, then you use the primary key.  That's what the primary key is for.  Trying to figure out the order of rows and using that order isn't going to work because that's not the relational model.  Databases are designed to allow concurrent changes, after all.

Comment: About as clear as mud. You've not given us any information as to what you're updating, where the updated information comes from or anything else. We have no idea what's in your generic List, how it got there or what's the purpose of it. ALL we've gotten so far is that you need to select then update. Even your pseudo code is confusing. We've STILL no idea as to the table or the data involved. STILL no idea why you're updating. STILL no closer to an answer. If Bacon Bits is right (as I well suspect s\he is) then your question, as it currently stands, has no valid answer.

Comment: I thought to take the primary key, but I can't do it with a "for", because if one item with id-4 was deleted - I have ids 1,2,3,5,6,7. and so the number of my "index" is wrong.

Comment: Give us a for instance. e.g. 'For instance, I have 5 rows (Columns ID, FirstName, LastName, Age) - values (5, Bob, Smith, 34) etc.... Then I need to update all the ages to (something else) for each row.' As I keep saying, PLEASE give us something more tangible.

Comment: Ok so my data is a place. I have string name, float longitude, float latitude, float zoneTime, and bool abroad. the columns have the same name.and the same data (real for a float) + ind id which is a primary key. to show the list of places in the form (so the user can choose one) I most select all the places. and if the user chane a place, I need to update the place. the simplest way is to select all together, and update it by name or id. but in my program it was taken one by one with a loop of for, and updated with the index of the list. so I wont don't change it if I can

Comment: Seems like you're going round ass-around-face about it. You're going through ALL the rows and saying to update all of them regardless. Far better to start on the subset of rows and work with them. And using the row number will kill you because that's 100% non-deterministic. You HAVE to use the primary key because that''s the only guarantee you have the row you're updating is the row you want to update. Row 3 now could be row 5 in haf a second time.

Comment: OK. I give up. It seems from the comments here that it does not make sense to stick with the "for". so I will change the program

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your data stored in a generic list called places then

```
Using (SqlConnection cn = GetMyDbConnectionHere())
{
    Using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.UpdatePlace", cn)
    {
        // Create your parameters for the command here - e.g. p_PlaceName
        foreach(Place place in places)
        {
            if(place.HasChanged)
            {
                p_PrimaryKey.value = place.primaryKey;
                p_PlaceName.value = place.placeName;
                p_PlaceLat.value  = place.lat;
                // And so on and so forth
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
         }
    }
}
```

All this code is straight off the top of my head and typed directly into SO on the web page - so I make no guarantee as to it being fully functional - but it should at least get you going... In addition there's zero error handling here - also a major no-no.